# Can I submit and deploy app from Xcode 8.3.3 without updating to Xcode 9 now that Xcode 9 is out?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, xcode9

I'm new to coding and the last update/migration left me so stuck I recoded the whole app instead. I've nearly finished my next app and realised instead of updating to `Xcode9`, maybe I could finish and deploy the app to the app store in and from `Xcode8.3.3` (it says swift compile language is `swift3`)?

Comment: Yes! Of course.

Comment: Yes. No issues. if it is compiling in XCode8.3.3.

Comment: That's a relief, as long as it's 64 bit architecture, it should work with all phones including iOS 11 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can upload your app without problems, don't worry!

Comment: Thanks, just to check, the deployed app should work with all devices as per usual including iOS 11 (I have 64 bit architecture coded)?

Comment: yes of course, a device with OS 11 can run an app created for previous versions.